# Difficulty connecting to MySQL remotely

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access, remote-server

When I am connected to the internet, I can connect to my local `MySQL` server with my public/internet `IP` address, using `MySQL` `workbench`.

However, using the same parameters, I can not connect to the same `MySQL` server from a website running on `PHP`. I use the code line below:

```
new mysqli("41.58.XX.XX", "username", "mysql_pswd", "db_name");
```

I get the following error message:

```
(HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '41.58.xx.xx'
```

**Note: My configuration includes granting all privileges to the user on all host** `'%'`

Please how can I do this correctly?

Comment: Any error messages you get?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes. "(HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '41.58.xx.xx'.

Comment: did you try other methods like `pdo`.

Comment: @AmirNoori Yes, I used PDO first, I get the same error msg.

Comment: First `ping` the address if it is replies then try a telnet to the address on port 3306 i.e. `telnet 41.58.xx.xx 3306` if this does not connect then you have a firewall issue. The ping will just check connectivity the telnet will check port availability. Jambo San!

Comment: maybe there is problem with PHP MySQL versions, if it is possible use latest versions.

Comment: @Namphibian I tried to telnet, but I got the message - "Connection to host lost. I turned off my firewall and tried again, I still got the same message.